# Making an variable constant after constructing it

Tags: c

I have a function that returns an array of strings depending on the OS running the code.

```
int arrayLength = getMeThatArrayLength();
char* someArray[arrayLenth];

populateTheArray(&someArray, arrayLength);
```

Once generated, the array should be immutable moving forward.
The data returned should not change throughout the program's lifetime.

Like if I had stored the data in these sort of variables:

```
const int cArrayLength;
const char* const* cSomeArray;
```

where `cArrayLength` would hold whatever `arrayLength` has and `cSomeArray` would hold whatever `someArray` has.

Direct assigning throws error and I understand why.

```
const int cArrayLength = arrayLength;
const char* const* cSomeArray = someArray;
```

Maybe I need an immutable pointer to the mutable array? I'm fairly new to C so I'm not completely sure but maybe the pointer could point to the array but it'd be immutable from the pointer's perspective and as an extensions from the function's which is holding that immutable pointer.

Is there a way of doing that?

Comment: "_Reassigning throws error_" Does it really? What error(s)? This should be totally possible. A pointer can be a `const` view of data that might not have been originally declared `const`, etc.

Comment: @underscore_d Sorry I meant "direct assigning". This is the error `cannot assign to variable with const-qualified type`

Comment: Note that your code isn’t making an existing variable constant, it’s creating a new variable that is a *copy* of the existing, non-`const` variable. That’s pretty much useless, since the risk of accidentally modifying the original variable doesn’t go away.

Comment: The close vote is wrong. This question is not seeking debugging help.

Comment: The line `char* someArray[arrayLength] = getMeThoseStrings();` appears to be using a function call to initialize an array, which is wrong. (Perhaps `getMeThoseStrings()` is a macro call that expands to an initializer?)

Comment: Can't you just use a type cast to add the constness: `const char * const *cSomeArray = (const char * const *)someArray;`?

Comment: @IanAbbott You're right, function shouldn't initialize that array. Fixed the code.

Comment: @IanAbbott When I tried declaring those variables in header file I got this error `assigning to const char** from const char* const* discards qualifiers` but not if I declare it as you wrote.

Comment: @distro.obs Where are you assigning a `const char **` to a `const char * const  *` and can't you change the type of the thing you are assigning to?

Comment: The duplicate vote is wrong. A question asking about a C solution for treating something as `const` after run-time initialization is not properly answered by a question tagged C++ and not C, especially where the top answer tells teh person to use a lambda expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C doesn't let you access non-`const` `extern/static/_Thread_local` data via `const`-qualified declarations.

You can't have (officially; practically it tends to work) a global `int arrayLength;` that's exposed elsewhere (in another translation unit) as `extern int const arrayLength;`.

What you can have is a `static/static _Thread_local` writable global that's accessed via an accessor that returns a pointer-to-const pointer to it.

Example code:

```
//PUBLIC HEADER
struct myvec{
    int arrayLegth;
    char const*const* someArray;
};
struct myvec const* getmyvec(void); 
/*const on structs works as if it make each memeber const:
     int const arrayLength
     char const*const*const someArray;
*/

///PRIVATE IMPLEMENTATION (in a C file that includes the header)
static struct myvec internal;
struct myvec const* getmyvec(void)
{
    if(internal.someArray) return &internal;
    //(allocate?+) fill internal ...
    return &internal;
}
```

The accessor method (as well as the officially unsupported way of exposing `int x;` as `extern int const x;`) rely on the type system.

The underlying data won't be in write-protected memory like it usually (implementation detail) would be if it was `static/extern/_Thread_local` data that was originally declared `const`. This means that you can cast away the `const` and then write to the data via the new pointer.

Using system-dependent mechanisms like `mprotect`* it's actually possible to mark a page of memory read-only so that attempts to write to it later generate segfaults, but that's a rather coarse and expensive operation that might not be worth it—the types-system-based protection could be sufficient in your use case.

---

`mprotect` is how program loaders usually implement write-protection for global data originally declared `const`: a linker will have aggregated all such data into a single contiguous block, the loader will load it, and then it will `mprotect` all of it as read-only in one system call.

Comment: In **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54831046/initialising-a-static-const-variable-from-a-function-in-c** is also code that implements this ...